# Android Studio can't create new project without errors

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

The gradle build fails and gives these 3 errors when I try to create a new project:

```
C:\Users\Ian\AndroidStudioProjects\BusApp\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.0.0\res\values-v23\values-v23.xml

Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.

Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
 com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Ian\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.0\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I set my mind sdk to 15 and target to 22 if that helps.

Comment: did you update your sdk? i think thats the problem

Answer (score 2):

Try change compileSdkVersion to 23

Answer (score 1):

Try setting compileSdkVersion to 23, that resolved my issue.  For more info follow this  youtube video
[Youtube Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pw4jKsOU7go)

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same error once, you have to restart android studio it will again build the gradle, this is worked for me.
Some times for the memory reason studio don't get succeed to build the gradle so try after restart the android studio may be this will also work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the support libraries v23 **you have to use** in your `build.gradle`

`compileSdkVersion 23`

You **can't** compile the support libraries v23 with api22.

Here you can find the ["official" post about it](https://plus.google.com/+ChrisBanes/posts/ekKcJwtCW9U).